# Wordpress - CPT and ACF Plugins

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I'm about starting developing my own theme by using CPT and ACF Plugins. I read some articles and reviews about CPT as well as ACF and most of the developers they love them because they are very easy to use and helpful. However some of them they gave very bad feedback in terms of security, stability and slowing down the performance of the website; even they said these plugins for non-technical developers which developing for cheap clients.

What do you think about this? because I like CPT and ACF very much once I tried doing things with them. However I don't want to put my self in a risk by using these plugins.

Also do you suggest another professional way to create Custom Post Type and Custom Fields? or do you prefer CPT and ACF anyway for even the advanced developer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all

It is depending on your requirements. If you have to create only one or two post type. I don't think it is really a need to use those plugins. Because both are heavy plugins.So better to use custom code to create post type. and custom field.

Regarding the plugins, It is true that CPT is more heavy then ACF. I have used ACF from the beginning. Before that CPT was my favourite. I came to know about the above complexity as i have much more experience with those plugins.

Comment: Thank you foe your comment. I have to create about five CPT. It is ok with me to code Custom Post Type and Custom Fields instead of using CPT and ACF Plugins. Could you please give me a very good resource to learn how to code them and using within the theme

Comment: This is for custom posttype https://wptheming.com/2010/08/custom-metabox-for-post-type/ and this for custom filed https://www.taniarascia.com/wordpress-part-three-custom-fields-and-metaboxes/

Comment: Please accept my answer by the click on the right icon.

Comment: So to finalize this, In terms of security and perormance, Do you prefer the CPT and ACF Plugins or the coding way? or it will be the same any way?

Comment: If you follow the wordpress rules, It is very secure from using plugins. Your site speed also depend on the using of number of pluigns.

Answer (score 0):

For CPT it's very truth.

You can do it with simple code, no plugins needed.

For ui use generator before add to theme functions, like this site:
https://generatewp.com/post-type/

For custom fields ACF is useful to UI elements, so just if it's a special value use ACF. Then just add metabox to cpt.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It seems useful